Bug en página de ayuda
Estaba buscando una API para resaltar código HTML y decidí usar la misma que usa esta página (stack overflow). Voy a la página de ayuda y me consigo con Google Code Prettify. Al presionar en el enlace consigo con el error 404. Este es el enlace: http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html. Estuve investigando y me encontré que esta es la API: https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-code-prettify/. Como se darán cuenta ya está archivada y no se mantiene desde el 2020. Recomiendo modificar el enlace caído por el repositorio original que es este
Edit
Me comentarón que viera la página en ingles de ayuda de StackOverflow quitarón este enlace y pusierón una biblioteca mas actualizada.
Aqui dejo lo que dice hoy:

Syntax highlighting for code

Code blocks can be highlighted using highlight.js. In many cases, the syntax highlighting language will be inferred from the question's tags.


Y lo que dice la página en español:

Resaltador de sintaxis para código

Los bloques de código pueden ser resaltados utilizando Google Prettify. En muchos casos el lenguaje a resaltar será inferido a partir de las etiquetas de la pregunta.



Si funciona bien para que tocarlo...

Técnicamente no es un bug, sino que falta actualizar la página de ayuda. Lo que no sé es si highlight.js se implementó solo en SO o también en los sitios que no están en inglés.

@FranciscoNuñezIALover Para agregar nuevos bugs y nuevas funcionalidades :)

no tiene sentido agregar nuevos bugs y nuevas funcionalidades si ya el sistema y la pagina funcionan bien como estan ...

Y al parecer efectivamente falta actualizar la página de ayuda. Según esta publicación en meta, ya está implementado highlight.js.

Releí la pregunta (prioricé de más el titulo) y me parece que me equivoqué con la etiqueta bug. La quito?

Además de corregir el enlace tendrían que colorear los códigos. El de c# no funciona, es cs.

printf("%d\n", 42);  /* ¿Cuál era
                    la pregunta? */


<blink>
  Odiarías esto si no estuviera
  dentro de un bloque de código.
</blink>


<!-- language: lang-js -->

    setTimeout(function () { alert("JavaScript"); }, 1000);


<!-- language: cs -->

    public static bool IsAwesome { get { return true; } }


<!-- language-all: lang-html -->


<!-- language-all: lang-none -->


<a href="http://example.com" title="example">example</a>


<!-- language-all: markdown -->
*Esto es cursiva* y _esto_ también.
**Esto es negrita** y __esto__ también.
Usa ***cursiva y negrita a la misma vez*** si ___tienes que hacerlo___.

